# HTML and CSS change table layout based on window size

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two columns in a row. It works fine on big window, but on a small window I would like to 'split' these two columns into different rows. So that each row has only one column. I do see a similar situation on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkJ3G/) (code below) which makes use of @media screen and (max-width: 500px). But the example is about paragraphs.

```
#dv-wrapper p {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {    
  #dv-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
  }

  #dv-wrapper p {
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

I don't know if my goal could be achieved with only HTML and CSS. Can anyone give me a hand please?

Comment: Please provide your code and not others'.

Comment: check bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like, so I can't answer, but I wonder, does it need to be a table. It sounds like you could do with two blocks using `inline-block`, which would be displayed side by side on a wide enough screen, but below one another on a narrower one. No need for media queries.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkJ3G/4/)

You may want to wrap your paragraphs into separate `divs` which makes it easier to control - This will basically give your paragraphs a full width of 100% on screens below 500px -

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

**Html**

```
<div class="table_data">
    <dl>
        <dt>1-1</dt>
        <dd>1-2</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>2-1</dt>
        <dd>2-2</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
dt, dd, dl {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
}
dl {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
dt, dd {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    dt, dd {
        width:50%;
        float:left;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1warz4r0/)